# On what basis we can calculate number of partitions in Hazelcast?

Tags: count, hazelcast

I want to calculate an optimum number of partitions for my Hazelcast cluster, however, I am unable to find a parameter to base this calculation on. 
The default partition of 271, may or may not be sufficient, which I am not sure.

For simplicity sake, if I assume that my cluster would have about 50 million entries split on 50 nodes, then what would be the ideal number of partitions and how to derive to this number?

Thank you,
Dilish

Answer (score 1):

A partition shouldn't be bigger than 50-100MB. 50MB is better though to have fast migration in scaling or failure situations. If the size is ok, it mainly depends on the number of configured partition threads. In general more partitions per node is always better, to get higher scalability factor, however if you use EntryProcessors quite a lot, you also want to higher the number of partition threads, to make sure partitions won't block each other (most often multiple partitions share a single partition thread). Last but not least you should round up to the next higher prime number for statistical distribution.

Comment: Thanks, so (object) size per partition & partition thread count would be my guiding factors to determine the number of partitions (rounded to next highest prime number). Is it a good idea to match the number of partition threads to be same as number of partitions ?

Comment: You can do it but it'll never really match up. There is a calculation like partitionId % threadcount, therefore there's no 1:1 assignment if both numbers are the same. If you want to make sure there's no sharing, you'll have to set it to a higher number but in general thread sharing is not too bad, you should have a very valid reason for doing so. And don't forget, you'll also have backup partitions (if backups are activated) which doubles the number of assigned partitions.

Answer (score 0):

In terms of performance you can also try thinking like this: how many threads can I run? and then figure out a prime number that's let's say 10 times bigger.